# Install CUDA-7.5 on a computer using GTX950 and Tesla K40

Tags: linux, cuda, graphic

I'm trying to do install CUDA-7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04, And I have both GTX950 and Tesla K40 inserted in my motherboard.

and the ***lspci | grep -i nvidia*** command gives the following result:

```
01:00.0 3D controlloer: NVIDIA Corporation GK110BGL [Tesla K40c] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM206 [GeForece GTX 950] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fba (rev a1)
```

I think I have successfully installed CUDA-7.5 on my computer, because I can actually run ***./smokeParticles*** sample in **NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples/bin/x86_64/linux/release/**.

But I have one question:

- How can I be sure that I'm actually using Tesla K40? Because the ***./smokeParticles*** sample is also successful after I unplug the 
  Tesla K40 form my motherboard. (I assume that GTX 950 is running the sample...)

Is there a command or something that can tell me I'm using Tesla K40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cuda sample, `deviceQuery` is used to test whether cuda is installed correctly and show basic information about each card. This will tell you a device number of each cuda device.

For example, I run it on my server:

```
$ ./deviceQuery |egrep '^Device [0-9]+'
Device 0: "GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
Device 1: "GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
Device 2: "GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
Device 3: "GeForce GTX 980 Ti"
```

In your cuda application, use `cudaSetDevice()` to select card to run. Look into the sample source to see how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved my day!!! Another question: when I'm using GTX 950 on Sample ./nbody, the commandline prints "Using device 1: GeForce GTX 950 > Compute 5.2 CUDA device: [GeForce GTX 950]", while the Tesla K40 prints "Using device 0: Tesla K40c > Compute 3.5 CUDA device: [Tesla K40c]". Can you tell me the difference between this "Compute 5.2/3.5 CUDA device"?

Comment: @CHEN Nvidia explains these cuda terminologies in its docs, especially "CUDA C Programming Guide". You can find it on nvidia cuda zone website. Before continue your journey on cuda samples, it is necessary to learn it the hard way by reading.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to *extend* [halfelfs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958529/halfelf) answer. His suggested solution is for sure correct but I don't consider it general. Just depending on a hard coded device number which has been returned from the command line may become to a trap once - for what ever reason - the OS changes the previously assigned device number.

My suggestion is this:

```
int getDeviceNumberByName( const char * deviceName )
{
   int deviceCount;
   cudaGetDeviceCount ( &deviceCount );
   for ( int currentDevice = 0 ; currentDevice < deviceCount ; ++currentDevice )
   {
      cudaDeviceProp deviceProperties;
      cudaGetDeviceProperties( &deviceProperties, currentDevice );
      if ( 0 == strcmp( deviceProperties.name, deviceName )
         return currentDevice;
   }
   return -1;        // not found
}
```

With this function you are very flexible and even when you change the underlying hardware it works.

**Description:**

Get the total count of installed NVIDIA devices and read the property of each device. Check if the device name matches the provided device name and if it does return the device number, otherwise return -1 if not found.